# Как найти ID того пользователя, указанного в большенстве объектов?

Tags: javascript

имеется такой объект, необходимо найти того юзера, кто имеет наибольшее количество групп (в contacts указаны они)

на этом примере я должен найти ID 65

тоесть юзер под id 65 имеет самое большое количество групп
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не изображением, чтобы отвечающим было легче копировать и тестировать фрагменты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вначале выбрать все массивы с контактами в новый, типа такого:

   ```
    let arr = test.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc.push(item.contacts);
        return acc;
    }, [])
   ```
2. Затем надо массив сделать плоским https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat, получится примерно так:

   ```
    let arrFlat = arr.flat();
   ```

   Результат будет примерно таким:

   ```
   [65, 45, 65, 23, 78, 90]
   ```
3. Дальше уже можно идти любыми путями, какими вы считаете нужными для подсчёта. Например можно сделать мапу, где ключ - ID, значение - количество вхождений и **потом найти максимумЫ из него**. Можно сразу цикл и подсчёт.

   ```
   const occurrences = [65, 45, 65, 23, 78, 90].reduce(function (acc, curr) {
     return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
   }, {});

   console.log(occurrences) // => {23: 1, 45: 1, 65: 2, 78: 1, 90: 1}
                                                     ^-----
   ```

---

Сразу мапу сформировать так:

```
let occurrences = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    curr.contacts.forEach(contact => {
        acc[contact ] ? ++acc[contact ] : acc[contact ] = 1
    })

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(occurrences) // => {23: 1, 45: 1, 65: 2, 78: 1, 90: 1}
                                                  ^-----
```

---

Строго говоря, можно было сразу делать двойной цикл (первый по VKGroup, второй - внутри по contacts) и сразу находить  максимальные вхождения. Но способ выше в п.1.2.3 наверное немного нагляднее.

---